# yii set class import path not working

Tags: yii

I want load controller form path: `application.controller.mobile.*`

e.g.: Access `{$host}/hello/word`

I expect yii load in **mobile** path:
 `application.controller.mobile.HelloController`

So I add this in config file, but it not work.

```
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
    'application.controllers.mobile.*',
),
```

Actual yii always load the `application.controller.HelloController`, It's not found.

I have muilt site (web2.0, mobile) in one application so only to do this for *namespace*

Comment: what is this mobile. is it a directory inside the controllers directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.**  If mobile is a directory inside controllers directory where you have saved all the controllers files then try this

```
'application.controllers.mobile.*',
```

**2.**  If mobile is a controller file inside the controllers directory then

```
'application.controllers.MobileController',
```

**3.**  If you want to access only the HelloController which is inside mobile directory which is further inside controllers directory then

```
'application.controllers.mobile.HelloController',
```

**4.**  If HelloController is inside controllers directory then

```
'application.controllers.HelloController',
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked out this myself but I think you should try this:

```
'import'=>array(
'application.models.*',
'application.components.*',
'application.controllers.*',
'application.controllers.mobile.*',
),
```

You might have to include controllers directory before including any other classes (controllers) inside of it.

Comment: No, it is not necessary to include the directory before including the classes